# What is the Kripke semantic for a linear temporal logic?

Tags: logic, linear-temporal-logic, temporal-logic, modal-logic

I've read that in general for a modal formula P, a world w and a Kripke frame ⟨W,R⟩

w⊨□P if and only if for every u∈W, if wRu then u⊢P

In case of LTL, being a modal logic, I assumed that the worlds are different moments in time and the relation R is the chain of "arrows" between those moments. However, in this case the semantic of □ in LTL would not correspond to the definition above.

What did I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LTL, you don't have $\diamond$ and $\Box$, but you have $X$ and $U$, meaning *next* and *until*, respectively.

In LTL, every world has a unique successor.

Next is defined as $w \models X \phi$ if $w' \models \phi$, where $w'$ is the successor of $w$.

Until is defined as follows: $w \models \phi U \psi$ if there exists $w''$ such that $w'' \models \psi$ and for every $w'$ between $w$ and $w''$, we have that $w' \models \phi$.

Now, from these modalities, we can construct other modalities, such as *globally*, $G \phi$, and *finally*, $F \phi$.  It is common to denote

- $X \phi$ as $\bigcirc \phi$
- $F \phi$ as $\diamond \phi$
- $G \phi$ as $\Box \phi$.

Comment: you start with "In LTL, you don't have ⋄ and ◻" and finish with "It is common to denote  as ⋄ and  as ◻". Isn't it up to personal preference?

Comment: I would rather call it _convention_ than _personal preference_, and in temporal logics, the convention is using the alphabetic modalities, e.g. $F$, $X$, $G$, and $AF$, $EF$, $AG$, $EG$, $A (\phi U \psi)$ and $E (\phi U \psi)$.  Meaning that CTL, CTL*, ATL and LTL are defined on the language using $A,E$ (when applicable), and $F,G,X$, and $U$.  Then we throw in the boxes and diamonds as _syntactic sugar_, if you will.

Comment: I'd remove the first sentence. It's an opinion at best and not supported by facts. Manna and Pnueli use $\bigcirc$, $\square$, $\diamond$ in their articles and reference books. Lamport's TLA doesn't have a next operator but he uses $\square$ and $\diamond$.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** The accessibility relation needs to be the reflexive transitive closure of what you had in mind.

Details:
Let $P$ be a set of atomic proposition. Write $\Sigma$ for $P$'s powerset. Write $T$ for $\Sigma^{\mathbb{N}}$ (infinite traces).

A Kripke frame $\langle W, R\rangle$ where the meaning of formulas agrees with that of the fragment of LTL using just $P$, boolean connectives, $\square$ and $\diamond$  would consist of $W = T\times\mathbb{N}$ (ie infinite traces with an index) and $R = \{~((\sigma,i),(\sigma,k))~|~\sigma\in T\wedge i\leq k\in\mathbb{N}~\}$.